# Fedora 26 sabnzbd install problem: conflicting requests - nothing provides python-sabyenc

Tags: fedora, software-installation, python, dnf

On recent Fedora 26 install, I encountered an error (shown below) attempting to install sabnzbd.

I found the wiki at https://sabnzbd.org/wiki/installation/install-fedora-centos-rhel.  From this wiki, I went to the nuxref repository at http://nuxref.com/nuxref-repository/ and clicked on the following link:

Fedora 26: nuxref-release-1.0.0-4.fc26.nuxref.noarch.rpm

Downloading the rpm, I selected the default action of "software install", which apparently installed the rpm.  Then I opened a bash terminal and executed `sudo dnf install sabnzbd`.  This resulted in the following error message:

```
Problem: conflicting requests
- nothing provides python-sabyenc >= 3.0.2 needed by sabnzbd-2:2.2.1-1.fc26.nuxref.noarch
```

Comment: Tried to self medicate.  Found https://sabnzbd.org/wiki/installation/sabyenc.html.  After skimming, I opened a bash terminal and executed "sudo pip install sabyenc --upgrade".  System response was "Successfully installed sabyenc-3.0.2". Then, I re-executed "sudo dnf install sabnzbd".  No joy, the problem persists, with same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need `python-sabynec` provided as an RPM, not pip install. You should probably contact the repository you are using, as it seems to be missing this.

The page you link to shows two separate repositories as sources; since this one isn't working, I'd suggest trying the second one.

Comment: Thanks to mattdm for his very interesting answer.  I just posted a message on the http://nuxref.com/nuxref-repository/ webpage, referencing this webpage; the message is "awaiting moderation".  I will followup, comment on effectiveness of mattdm's answer, and score mattdm's answer.

Comment: The http://nuxref.com/nuxref-repository/ webpage responded, notifying that he updated his repository; installation went okay.  I surmise that mattdm's response was directly on point.  BTW...  Separate problem starting sabnzbd after following webpage's instructions; I posted 2nd message to http://nuxref.com/nuxref-repository/ webpage.  If no joy, I will start a separate stackexchange query.

Comment: Partially off-topic but still plausibly valuable...  On the http://nuxref.com/nuxref-repository/ webpage, I (steve schooler) submitted three replies (questions/comments) dated 9-10-2017, 9-11-2017, and 9-12-2017.  The site admin responded to my queries, which allowed me to resolve both an installation problem and a subsequent launching problem.